# Angularjs: Sorting not working in ui-grid with CellTemplate data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-filters, ui-grid

I am very new to angular ui-grid. 
I am displaying data using cell template but sorting is not working. 
I want to sort that particular column using 'username'.

Can anyone please help me with this.

```
{
  field: 'usernameandgender', 
  width: '29%',
  displayName: 'Dr. İsim / Uzmanlık', 
  name:'username' ,
  cellTemplate:'
      <div style="height:47px;">
         <span style="font-size:15px;">{{row.entity.username}}</span> -
         <span style="color:gray; font-weight:normal;font-size:13px;">
              {{row.entity.gender}}
         </span>
         <br/>
      </div>'
 }
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the field value to 'username'. It should work.

I used the same type of cell template to display icon based on true/false, and though it is displaying lock icon in grid, I can filter on basis of true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue and once providing field to be the name as in html, the issue resolved.
For eg: Provided this code in controller "agentId" : {
field :'agentId',                          
headerTooltip: true,
headerCellClass : "text_center",
},

for {{row.entity.agentId}}